# How to tell if items occur sequentially in a list in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to figure out how to more cleanly determine if a particular item occurs in my list sequentially

for example suppose I have a list:

```
my_list=[1,2,2,2,4,5,1,0]
```

in the above example repeated instances of 1 do not occur sequentially in the list but all instances of 2 do.  The only way I can seem to figure out how to do this is very clumsy

```
def check_sequencing(some_list,item_to_check):
    prev_instance = 0
    difference_list = []
    for counter, item in enumerate(some_list):
        if item_to_check == item:
        difference_list.append(counter - prev_instance)
        prev_instance = counter
    if set(difference_list[1:]) == set([1]):
        return 'True'
    else:
        return 'False'
```

I am trying to avoid importing another library (numpy) I was just sure when I started down this road that their would be a one liner but I can't find it.

Comment: Do you need to handle sequences where an item occurs both sequentially and non-sequentially (e.g. [1,1,2,1])?

Comment: That would be an interesting extension but not right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> collections.Counter(x[0] for x in itertools.groupby(my_list)).get(1, 0) > 1
True
>>> collections.Counter(x[0] for x in itertools.groupby(my_list)).get(2, 0) > 1
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to do this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> any(len(list(n[1])) >= 2 for n in itertools.groupby(l))
True
```

If you want to avoid using `len(list(gen))`, you could use something like this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> any(sum(1 for i in n[1]) >= 2 for n in itertools.groupby(l))
True
```

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: It returns `True` for me. Should it return `False` instead?

Comment: That's what I gathered from the question, given that not all instances of `1` are sequential.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Without seeing what should happen in the case of OP's example list, I can't tell for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this time i have a real one-liner that works:

```
all(x==i for x in L[L.index(i):len(L)-[k for k in reversed(L)].index(i)])
```

If it's true, then it occurs more than once. Replace `L` with your list and `i` with the term you're searching for.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to correct your answer I learned something from this